# synchronize two linux over area

Tags: linux

is it possible to synchronize two linux machine over internet? thanks

Any solutions using any Technique
?

Comment: Synchronize in what way?

Comment: any way... two server in different countries

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: is this called Linux Data Replication?

Comment: What are you trying to sync, you need to be more specific to what you want to sync.

Comment: There's file syncing, mail syncing, process syncing - basically everything that exists on a computer could be synced to another computer. Unless you specify what needs to be synced, we can't even tell where this question belongs, on SO, SU or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g. `rsync`. "Synchronize" can mean a lot of different things though, below is a prototype rsync-command:

`rsync --archive --delete --update /directory/to/sync $REMOTE_HOST:/directory/on/remote/host`

You will have to carefully read `man rsync` or other resources on the available switches and behaviours though, it is a versatile program.

Most often, I find rsync the "correct" way to do it, without reinventing the wheel.